# Will the user get notified when a Chrome extension changed its permission requirement in an update?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, updates

I always have concern about my online privacy and this question is about Chrome extension. When you install an extension, it asks for some permissions. If in later updates it updates its permission requirements and asks more, will the user get notified? Or it just silently get them (since it's already been installed)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is pretty strict about permissions and never grants any extension
any permission silently. User authorization is always required.

If the update for the extension asks for more permissions and you
don't grant them, the update might fail, or the application will fail
when it does an operation that requires this permission.